# How to get all pixel values of raster within a GeoJSON FeatureCollection in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster, geojson, query

I need to extract all pixel values in a raster within a GeoJSON mask, using [`ST_Intersects`](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Intersects.html).

Attempt (throws `invalid GeoJson representation`):

```
select row_to_json(t) from (select * from table_name where st_intersects(st_transform(st_setsrid(ST_geomfromgeojson('{"type":"FeatureCollection","features": []}'), 4326), 3857), rast)) as t;
```

It seems `FeatureCollection` type `GeoJSON` is not straight-forward. How can I wrap this?

Comment: The GeoJSON is a dummy, obviously. A simple polygon like [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e454a388592808b6c753003c5da0463a) throws the same error.